# How to exclude a Spring Boot Component from running in JUnit unit tests?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

> How to exclude a Spring Boot Component from running in JUnit unit tests?

**What I've tried**

Please correct me if I'm wrong. `@ComponantScan` is excluding a class globally, both in main & test?

Since I don't want exclude my it globally, **only during unit tests**, is there any way to do that?

```
@Component
public class DatabaseInitialization {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("app@test.com");
        user.setPassword("1234567");
        user.setFirstName("Charle");
        user.setLastName("P.");
        user.setIbanCode(2641874);
        user.setBicCode(63215472);
        user.setFriendsList("[]");

        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post more information about what you want and what you have tryed?

Comment: Thank you @WilliamAndrésBernal for your response. It's now updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.mocking-beans) annotation replaces a bean with another bean implemented by a Mockito mock. You're not going to stub any methods on the mock. You only care that the bean is replaced with a bean that does nothing. Inside your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {

    @MockBean
    private DatabaseInitialization databaseInitialization;
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood your exact use case but this link might be useful to learn about how to exclude autoconfiguration classes while running test cases https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exclude-auto-configuration-test

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a `@PostConstruct` from running during tests:

Create the class containing the post construct in your test folder and add the `@Primary` annotation so it takes precedence over the class in your main project as bellow.

```
@Primary
public class ClassContainingPostConstruct{   

}
```